# Add a condition to a query from another table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have these tables:
`rome_sub(id_rome,id_sub)`,
`rome_holland(id_rome,id_holland)`

What I want to do is make a query like

```
SELECT * FROM rome_sub where id_sub=X
```

And add to it this condition:

```
id_holland IN (Y,Z)
```

Comment: Please, clarify your question. Right now it is hard to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Get every id_rome associated with id_sub=x in the table rome_sub and associated with id_holland IN (Y,Z) in the table rome_holand.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are looking for the EXISTS or IN clause:

```
select * 
from rome_sub 
where id_sub = 'X'
and id_rome in 
(
  select id_rome 
  from rome_holland 
  where id_holland in ('Y','Z')
);
```

Or:

```
select * 
from rome_sub 
where id_sub = 'X'
and exists 
(
  select *
  from rome_holland 
  where id_holland in ('Y','Z')
  and rome_holland.id_rome = rome_sub.id_rome
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`JOIN` the two tables:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.* 
FROM rome_sub AS s
INNER JOIN rome_holland AS h ON s.id_rome = h.id_rome
where s.id_sub = 'X'
  AND h.id_holland IN ('Y', 'Z');
```

Comment: I don't know whats asked for, bu this might perhaps result in extra rows returned, if there are duplicates in rome_holland.

Comment: @jarlh - Yes, but the OP didn't add more details, he can also add `distinct` to eliminate those duplicated.